# MySQL GROUP BY doesn't work when migrated to SQL Server 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm moving my Delphi application from MySQL to SQL server 2012. In MySQL I had this query:

```
SELECT *,(XS+S+M+L+XL+XXL+[1Size]+Custom) as Total FROM StockData  
GROUP BY StyleNr,Customer,Color  
ORDER BY StyleNr,Customer,Color
```

And it worked perfectly. But in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 this query says

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'StockData.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I change my query to:

```
SELECT *,([XS]+[S]+[M]+[L]+[XL]+[XXL]+[1Size]+[Custom])  total
 FROM [dbo].[stockdata]
 GROUP BY ID,StyleNr,Customer,Color
 ORDER BY StyleNr,Customer,Color
```

Then I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'dbo.stockdata.XS' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Any ideas?

Here is the table's design view:

[image]

Comment: Is the `(StyleNr,Customer,Color)` combination unique? If yes, simply remove the `GROUP BY` line. If not, then the MySQL query was giving wrong, indeterminate results.

Comment: this is mainly to keep duplicate values from appearing because in the last database there were allot of duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL Server is working as expected. You must include all items in your `SELECT` list in either a `GROUP BY` or in an aggregate function:

```
SELECT *,(XS+S+M+L+XL+XXL+[1Size]+Custom) as Total 
FROM StockData  
-- GROUP BY ID,StyleNr,Customer,Color, XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,[1Size],Custom
ORDER BY StyleNr,Customer,Color
```

Or you might be able to use:

```
SELECT StyleNr,Customer,Color, SUM(XS+S+M+L+XL+XXL+[1Size]+Custom) as Total 
FROM StockData  
GROUP BY StyleNr,Customer,Color
ORDER BY StyleNr,Customer,Color;
```

Comment: forgot to add the ID near the Group By but thanks it worked :)

Comment: @bluefeet why not just remove the `GROUP BY` from the 1st query?

Comment: @ypercube you are right it is not needed especially if the `ID` field is unique the total will be incorrect.

Comment: Because there are allot of duplicate Style,Customer,Color fields and i want to see only distinct ones :)

Answer (score 1):

All columns in an aggregate query must either be used by an aggregate function or a group by. Try only selecting the columns you require rather than * I.e. select stylenr, customer, color, ([...] ) as Total from.

This is a SQL standard way of dealing with aggregates, you'd get a similar error in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this approach:

```
with OrdinalOnGroup
(
    SELECT 
        Ordinal = rank() over(partition by StyleNr, Customer, Color order by id) 
        , *, (XS+S+M+L+XL+XXL+[1Size]+Custom) as Total 
    FROM StockData  
)
select * 
from OrdinalOnGroup
where Ordinal = 1;
```

PARTITION BY denotes the grouping of related information, this is called [windowing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/working-with-window-functions-in-sql-server/)